# Find duration by grouping by ID and other specific conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

**Objective:**

I have a dataset, df, that I would like to group by the ID and find the duration based on certain conditions: Focus == True, Read == True, and ID != ""

```
ID            Date                   Focus        Read


A             1/2/2020 5:00:00 AM    True         True
A             1/2/2020 5:00:05 AM    True         True
              1/3/2020 6:00:00 AM    True
              1/3/2020 6:00:05 AM    True         
B             1/4/2020 7:00:00 AM    True         True
B             1/4/2020 7:00:02 AM    True         True
B             1/4/2020 7:00:10 AM    True         True
```

**I would like this output:**

```
ID                          Duration

A                           5 sec
B                           10 sec
```

**dput:**

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", 
"A", "B"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(1:7, .Label = c("1/2/2020 5:00:00 AM", 
"1/2/2020 5:00:05 AM", "1/3/2020 6:00:00 AM", "1/3/2020 6:00:05 AM", 
"1/4/2020 7:00:00 AM", "1/4/2020 7:00:02 AM", "1/4/2020 7:00:10 AM"
), class = "factor"), Focus = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "True ", class = "factor"), Read = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "True "), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names     = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

What I have tried:

```
  df %>% group_by(ID)
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy_hms(Date), 
     cond = Focus == "TRUE" & Read=="TRUE" & ID != "" , 
     grp = cumsum(!cond)) %>%
 filter(cond) %>%
 group_by(grp) %>%
 summarise(starttime = first(Date), 
        endtime = last(Date), 
        duration = difftime(endtime, starttime, units = "secs")) %>%
 select(-grp)
```

However, this is not grouping by the ID, as I do not see this in my output.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `filter` first based on the 'True' values in 'Read', convert the 'Date' to 'Datetime' class, grouped by 'ID', get the 'Duration' as the difference in seconds between the `first` and `last` value of 'Date'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
   filter(as.logical(trimws(Read)), as.logical(trimws(Focus))) %>%
   mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(Duration = difftime(last(Date), first(Date), units = "secs"))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  ID    Duration
#  <fct> <drtn>  
#1 A      5 secs 
#2 B     10 secs
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210706/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-find-duration-by-grouping-by-id-and-other-specific).